# Ionic ngcordova uploading video while capturing

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, ngcordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

Hi sorry for this noob post. But anyway I would just like to ask if its possible to upload the video while capturing it? if yes, how can I achieve it, or are there any API or Plugin I can use to achieve this? Thanks! By the way I'm using Saas(Firebase) as storage for my media files.

Comment: uploading a video while capturing is a bad  idea. what if user canceld the video or do not like to  send the video. Sending the video after the user is captured using ftp is the best way ??? and by your way it is not possible i think

Comment: Well this is disappointing but you have a point. Anyway thanks for your reply @MohanGopi